# MYSQL I need to remove older records from my result set

Tags: mysql

I have almost got it, but not quite.  I am returning the data I need but I only want to output the latest paymentDate for each memberID.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT a.mID, a.ageGroup,a.dayAvail,a.startTime,b.memberType,b.paymentDate,b.id FROM referrals a
GROUP BY b.id
LEFT JOIN membership b ON a.mID=b.memberID
WHERE a.ageGroup='Young Adult'
ORDER BY b.memberID,b.paymentDate DESC
```

My result returned is:

```
memberID    ageGroup      dayAvail  startTime   memberType    paymentDate    b.id
226      Young Adult    Wednesday    6:30 PM    Associate      8/31/2013     869
226      Young Adult    Wednesday    6:30 PM    Associate1     14/30/1993    158
1262    Young Adult    Thursday    7:00 PM    Clinical        7/1/2013      762
1262    Young Adult    Thursday    7:00 PM    Clinical        3/23/2010     610
1271    Young Adult    Tuesday    5:30 PM    Clinical         8/1/2013      687
1271    Young Adult    Tuesday    5:30 PM    Associate1      16/18/2010     619
```

Based upon paymentDATE for each memberID, I only want the LATEST paymentDate returned (or I guess, the LAST b.id for each memberID)

Thank you.

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect.  I don't see how it could return any result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY` with `a.mID` instead of `b.id`. Please try with the following query

```
SELECT a.mID, a.ageGroup,a.dayAvail,a.startTime,b.memberType,MAX(b.paymentDate),b.id 
FROM referrals a    
LEFT JOIN membership b ON a.mID=b.memberID
GROUP BY a.mID
WHERE a.ageGroup='Young Adult'
ORDER BY a.mID
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I initially got an error message.  I rearranged the order of commands to the following and it worked.  Thank you again.   

    `SELECT a.mID, a.ageGroup, a.dayAvail, a.startTime, b.memberType, MAX( b.paymentDate ) , b.id
    FROM referrals a
    LEFTJOIN membership b ON a.mID = b.memberID
    WHERE a.ageGroup ='Young Adult'
    GROUPBY a.mID`

Comment: You are welcome. I'm updating my query according to your feedback. Thank you too.